# warnings trying to start cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

When I try to start cakephp it shows me some warnings messages:

> Warning: SplFileInfo::openFile(.../cake_2_0/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map): failed to open stream: Permission denied in .../cake_2_0/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 357
>
> Warning (512): SplFileInfo::openFile(cake_2_0/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_cake_dev_en-us) [splfileinfo.openfile]: failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 357]
>
> Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 325]

I'm using xampp on linux and as far as I know writing and reading permissions are enabled within the folders.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug report there http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2172 but it was considered as not being a bug.

Also try this

```
chgrp -R www-data app/tmp
chmod -R g+rw app/tmp 
find app/tmp -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

Hope it would help you

Comment: thanks I solved changing user name permission of the user name using apache for the apt/tmp folder

Answer (score -1):

You should check the version of php ^ ^
Cake requires php 5.2.8 or newer